# TrailHead Error: Faraday::ResourceNotFound. Message: NOT_FOUND: The requested resource does not exist

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-connect, lightning-design-system, trailhead

I am working **TrailHead** project related to Lightning connect, as part of the challenge synced external objects into Dev Org and changed one of the field type to external lookup relation. every thing modified according to the task description but while verifying the challenge getting below error:
[image]

Challenge Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/project/quickstart-lightning-connect/quickstart-lightning-connect4

Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: May want to check spelling including case, etc. Is always a good idea when using Trailhead to copy and paste field names and class names from the instructions into your code.

Comment: Most of the configuration are auto generated  with the external data source in this challenge, so no manual field creation are there point issues with field names. There is a Namespace before the fields or object names like (frst__Orders__c, frst__customerID__c)

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was because in an earlier trail I had done some other badges that setup a namespace in my Trailhead Playground. That meant that my API names where different and hence nothing gets validated any more. Dang it. Ofcourse the namespace change cant be reverted I dont think so Im stuck now. Have to create a new playground and redo.